# How do I check if another checkbox is checked and perform the function again with added conditions?

Tags: javascript, html

So I was tasked with creating a menu in which the user will choose between four noodles, four main dishes, and three sides. The sides will multiply the price of the main dish. The catch is that for every noodle the user checked, it will be incremented to the total price by 50%. So, if the user pays $120 and chooses two noodles, it will be $180.

I know that the checkbox will call for two functions, but I have no clue as to how it would work only if there are two or more checked checkboxes. Can someone help or guide me into how to actually perform this?

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/261k3efq/)**

```js
function pmodel() {
  Model();
  finalCost();
}

function Model() {
  if (document.querySelector('input[name="NDLS"]:checked')) {
    document.getElementById("MMD").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("ADDONS").disabled = false;

  } else {
    document.getElementById("MMD").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("ADDONS").disabled = true;
  }

}

function total() {
  var selected1 = document.querySelector('input[name="MD"]:checked').value;
  var selected2 = document.querySelector('input[name="ADDONS"]:checked').value;
  //var totals = 0;

  totals = (selected1 * selected2);
  finalCost(totals);

}


function finalCost(totals) {
  //totals += (totals * document.querySelector('input[id="PMODEL"]').value);

  document.getElementById("amount").value = totals;
}
```

```html
<fieldset id="MNDLS">
  <legend>Noodles</legend>
  <input type="checkbox" name="NDLS" id="PNDLS" value="0.5" onclick="pmodel()">
  <label for="Model">Spaghetti</label><br>

  <input type="checkbox" name="NDLS" id="PNDLS" value="0.5" onclick="pmodel()">
  <label for="Model">Carbonara</label><br>

  <input type="checkbox" name="NDLS" id="PNDLS" value="0.5" onclick="pmodel()">
  <label for="Model">Lasagna</label><br>

  <input type="checkbox" name="NDLS" id="PNDLS" value="0.5" onclick="pmodel()">
  <label for="Model">Plain</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="MMD" disabled>
  <legend>Main Dish</legend>
  <input type="radio" name="MD" value="50" onclick="total()">
  <label>Chicken Wings ($50)</label><br>

  <input type="radio" name="MD" value="55" onclick="total()">
  <label>Chicken Breast ($55)</label><br>

  <input type="radio" name="MD" value="60" onclick="total()">
  <label>Pork Cutlets ($60)</label><br>

  <input type="radio" name="MD" value="65" onclick="total()">
  <label>Steak($65)</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="ADDONS" disabled>
  <legend>Sides</legend>
  <input type="radio" name="ADDONS" value="1" onclick="total()">
  <label>Nothing (100%)</label><br>

  <input type="radio" name="ADDONS" value="1.5" onclick="total()">
  <label>Softdrinks (150%)</label><br>

  <input type="radio" name="ADDONS" value="2" onclick="total()">
  <label>Softdrinks and Fries (200%)</label>
</fieldset>

<br>
<p><strong>Amount (US$)</strong>: <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" value="" /></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't use same ID more than once, they should be unique.

Instead of that you can set your checkboxes with same class (just for ease selecting) and then count how many of them are checked:

```js
  function pmodel() {
      var count = 0;
      var list=document.getElementsByClassName("PNDLS");
      for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) { if(list[i].checked) { count++; } } 
      console.log(count);
    }
```

```html
 <fieldset id="MNDLS">
      <legend>Noodles</legend>
      <input type="checkbox" name="NDLS" class="PNDLS" value="0.5" onclick="pmodel()">
      <label for="Model">Spaghetti</label><br>

      <input type="checkbox" name="NDLS" class="PNDLS" value="0.5" onclick="pmodel()">
      <label for="Model">Carbonara</label><br>

      <input type="checkbox" name="NDLS" class="PNDLS" value="0.5" onclick="pmodel()">
      <label for="Model">Lasagna</label><br>

      <input type="checkbox" name="NDLS" class="PNDLS" value="0.5" onclick="pmodel()">
      <label for="Model">Plain</label>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="MMD" disabled>
      <legend>Main Dish</legend>
      <input type="radio" name="MD" value="50" onclick="total()">
      <label>Chicken Wings ($50)</label><br>

      <input type="radio" name="MD" value="55" onclick="total()">
      <label>Chicken Breast ($55)</label><br>

      <input type="radio" name="MD" value="60" onclick="total()">
      <label>Pork Cutlets ($60)</label><br>

      <input type="radio" name="MD" value="65" onclick="total()">
      <label>Steak($65)</label>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="ADDONS" disabled>
      <legend>Sides</legend>
      <input type="radio" name="ADDONS" value="1" onclick="total()">
      <label>Nothing (100%)</label><br>

      <input type="radio" name="ADDONS" value="1.5" onclick="total()">
      <label>Softdrinks (150%)</label><br>

      <input type="radio" name="ADDONS" value="2" onclick="total()">
      <label>Softdrinks and Fries (200%)</label>
    </fieldset>

    <br>
    <p><strong>Amount (US$)</strong>: <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" value="" /></p>
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured out the rest of the code from your comment.